# gradle - add clover params to each subproject

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle based project with numerous subprojects. I want to run clover on all of these but my config seems insistent on having the **clover.license** file in every subproject folder and a specific `clover` section in every subproject build file.

How would I specify the *clover* parama in the main project and have these applied to each subproject?

snip from build.gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.clover'

  clover {
      licenseLocation = new File(rootDir, 'clover.license')
      report {
        html = true
      }
  }

  dependencies {
      clover 'com.cenqua.clover:clover:3.2.0'
  }
```

> Error message from `./gradlew cloverGenerateReport`:
>
> service_name:cloverAggregateDatabases FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':service_name:cloverAggregateDatabases'.
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid or missing License.. Please visit http://my.atlassian.com to obtain a valid license.

Answer (score 1):

Include this in the **buildscript** section of the subproject **build.gradle** files:

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-clover-plugin:2.0.1'
}
```